# Morawetz's two $L^p$ inequalities

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces, proof-explanation

I'm reading Morawetz's [*Two $L^p$ Inequalities*](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1969-75-06/S0002-9904-1969-12403-1/S0002-9904-1969-12403-1.pdf), in which two global inequalities for $p>1$ are presented.  Here $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is an $L^p$ norm.

$$\frac{\lVert X\rVert^p + \lVert Y \rVert^p}{2}-\left\lVert \frac{X + Y}{2} \right\rVert^p \ge a \left\lVert \frac{X - Y}{2} \right\rVert^{p/s} \left( \frac{\lVert X\rVert^p + \lVert Y \rVert^p}{2} \right)^{1-1/s}, \tag{Ia}\label{Ia}$$

where $a$ only depends on $p$ and is strictly greater than one,

$$s =
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{ for } p < 2 \\
p/2 &\text{ for } p \ge 2,
\end{cases}
$$

$$\frac{\lVert X\rVert^p + \lVert Y \rVert^p}{2} \le \left\lVert \frac{X + Y}{2} \right\rVert^p \left( 1 + b_1 \left( \frac{\lVert X - Y \rVert}{\lVert X + Y \rVert} \right)^2 + b_2 \left( \frac{\lVert X - Y \rVert}{\lVert X + Y \rVert} \right)^p \right), \tag{Ib}\label{Ib}$$

where $b_1$ and $b_2$ are constants depending only on $p$.  Then four variables are introduced

\begin{align}
A &= \frac{X + Y}{2} \\
D &= \frac{X - Y}{2} \\
r &= \frac{\lVert D \rVert}{\lVert A \rVert} \\
m &= \left( \frac{\lVert X\rVert^p + \lVert Y \rVert^p}{2} \right)^{1/p}
\end{align}

so as to give a range of the ratio $\lVert A \rVert/m$.  In the article, it's claimed that

$$(1+b_1r^2+b_2r^p)^{1/p} \le \lVert A \rVert/m \le (1-(cr\lVert A \rVert/m)^{p/s})^{1/p},$$

where $c = c(p) <1$.

*However I got $-1/p$ instead of $1/p$ for the power on the LHS and $c = a^{s/p} > 1$ instead of $c < 1$ on the RHS.  Have I made any errors?*

---

Equation \eqref{Ia} can be simplified to

\begin{align}
m^p - \lVert A \rVert^p &\ge a \lVert D \rVert^{p/s} m^{p(1 - 1/s)} \\
1 - (\lVert A \rVert/m)^p &\ge a (r \lVert A \rVert/m)^{p/s} \\
1 - a (r \lVert A \rVert/m)^{p/s} &\ge  (\lVert A \rVert/m)^p \\
(1 - a (r \lVert A \rVert/m)^{p/s})^{1/p} &\ge  (\lVert A \rVert/m).
\end{align}

Equation \eqref{Ib} can be simplified to

\begin{align}
m^p &\le \lVert A \rVert^p (1 + b_1r^2 + b_2r^p) \\
(1 + b_1r^2 + b_2r^p)^{-1/p} &\le \lVert A \rVert/m.
\end{align}

Thank you in advance for any comments or suggestions.

Comment: It was $s=p/2$ for $p>2$ in the paper.

Comment: @Jack What's the *difference*? $s=2/2=1$

Comment: The value of $s$ is not defined in the paper. I meant to say you caught a typo.

Comment: @Jack Sorry for having misunderstood your previous comment.  Though this paper was published decades ago, this reminds me how academic journal publishers are making profits with little costs nowadays.  It's possible that the reviewers overlooked this due to whatever reasons.  Or we don't even know *who* is the reviewer.